# How to install SIGAR on Ubuntu-based Linux?

Tags: java, spring, maven, ubuntu, sigar

I am using SIGAR in a java project with Maven and Spring. I have the Maven Dependency and Maven Repository included in my `pom.xml` file, as described in this link:
http://mavenhub.com/mvn/thirdparty-uploads/org.hyperic/sigar/1.6.5.132

Furthermore, I am launching the program using Jetty (which launches the .war file created by `mvn install`).

However, SIGAR still won't work. Aparently I also need to install libsigar-amd64-linux-1.6.4.

So I downloaded that file, but now I have no idea what to do with it. How do I fix this? Where do I put that file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the solution. 
I had to download SIGAR from the [official source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/files/).

Then I had to copy/paste the entire "lib" folder (with all the `.so` and `.dll` and whatnot) into the folder "main/src/webapp" of the project, which is used by Spring to store needed apps (or so I assume).

Then after running `mvn install`, checking the "target" folder and running the newly generated `.war` file, everything runs as expected.

Comment: and what if the project is not a web project, it's a maven java application only??

Answer (score 4):

I believe it needs to be put into your programs library folder, alongside the "sigar.jar" file.

If you plan to run your program on other OS variants, you should also have a bunch of ".dll", ".so" and ".dylib" files in the same lib folder.

Edit:
You can download sigar at the link below, it contains the lib files for all major platforms: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/?source=navbar

Answer (score 4):

To install sigar on Linux, here is a copy/paste option:

```
wget https://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sigar/sigar/1.6/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.tar.gz
tar xvf hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.tar.gz
cd hyperic-sigar-1.6.4

# INSTALL
sudo cp sigar-bin/lib/libsigar-`dpkg --print-architecture`-`uname -s | tr '[:upper]' '[:lower]'`.so /usr/lib
```

Comment: aitorhh please check @dambo14 's comment

Answer (score 3):

@aitorhh This actually works,
**But had some errors in your code, this works:

```
wget https://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sigar/sigar/1.6/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.tar.gz
tar xvf hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.tar.gz
cd hyperic-sigar-1.6.4

# INSTALL
sudo cp sigar-bin/lib/libsigar-`dpkg --print-architecture`-`uname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`.so /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 3):

just install sigar lib:

```sh
sudo apt install libhyperic-sigar-java
```

this works for me.

Comment: This answer worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04. The `libhyperic-sigar-java` package in the repos is version 1.6.4, which is the latest (there hasn't been an updated release in 10 years).