# sigar .so files on Eclipse project using Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, sigar

I have a Maven project in Eclipse, where i added the Sigar library using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This was compiling and executing smoothly under eclipse. When i created an executable jar i was getting an error, that the `.so` file doesn't exist in the java.library.path.

```
DEBUG Sigar  - no libsigar-amd64-linux.so in java.library.path
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no libsigar-amd64-linux.so in java.library.path
```

After some research and reading (ok, more than some) i copied the lib folder of sigar (the one that holds all the .so files) under my project (i was not sure if I have to copy it to a specific place, so i put it under the project's root) and changed the maven dependency to that:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/Sigar_lib</workingDirectory>
            <mainClass>my.package.name.MyClass</mainClass>
            <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
        </configuration>            
    </dependency>
```

Tried all different approaches to the `<workingDirectory>` tag, with/without the build directory, forward/back slash and so on. Every time the jar fails to execute with the same error.

Any help please? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to copy/paste the entire "lib" folder (with all the .so and .dll and whatnot) into the folder "main/src/webapp according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894128/how-to-install-sigar-on-ubuntu-based-linux ?

Comment: @Aurelien I have seen that thread, but i dont have such a folder.

Answer (score 0):

please consider using [Apache Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) in order to build your executable jar. You can configure what kind of resources you want to have in your final Uber jar . See details [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

Example

```
<filter>
      <artifact>*:*</artifact>
       <includes>
            <include>xxx/*.so</include>
      </includes>
 </filter>
```

Hope that helps.